# How to convert A "hours and minutes and seconds" string to HH:MM:SS format?

Tags: python

In python, I am trying to make an alarm system where it converts "x Hours y Minutes and z Seconds" to the x:y:z format
For example:

```
5 hours 20 minutes 6 seconds
05:20:06

1 hour 25 seconds
01:00:25
```

This is my code, but it seems scuffed:

```
time_string = '1 hour and 25 seconds'

correction = time_string.replace('and ', '')
duration = correction.replace(' hour', ':').replace(' minute', ':').replace(' second', ':').replace(' ','').replace('s', '')
    if 'minute' not in correction and 'second' not in correction:
        duration = duration + '00:00'
    elif 'minute' not in correction and 'second' in correction:
        duration = duration.replace(':',':00:')
    elif 'second' not in correction:
        duration = duration + '00' 
    secs = sum(int(x) * 60 ** i for i, x in enumerate(reversed(duration.split(':'))))
```

How do I improve it?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to convert to a Python `datetime` object (or perhaps `timedelta`) though?

Comment: I think so but I was preferring an answer without any use of modules, plus I am not very familiar with the datetime docs. I was looking through before asking this question but it did not help me approach this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns total number of seconds, which seems to be what you wanted:

```
def parsex(s):
    hh = mm = ss = 0
    for word in s.split():
        word = word.lower()
        if word.isdigit():
            save = word
        elif word.startswith('hour'):
            hh = int(save)
        elif word.startswith('minute'):
            mm = int(save)
        elif word.startswith('second'):
            ss = int(save)
    return (hh*60+mm)*60+ss

print(parsex('1 hour and 30 seconds'))
print(parsex('2 hours 15 minutes 45 seconds'))
```

Comment: Thanks, also to convert to hh:mm:ss value should I just do this?
t = str(hh)+':'+'str(mm)+':'+str(ss)

Comment: Well, you'd want to pad the string with zeros:  like `f"{hh:02}:{mm:02}:{ss:02}"`.  Or, if you need to do date math, you can create a datetime object.

Answer (score 1):

**You can use datetime library to convert this type of string to proper formatted string.**

```
from datetime import datetime

def format_time(string):
    format_string = ''
    if 'hour' in string:
        if 'hours' in string:
            format_string += '%H hours '
        else:
            format_string += '%H hour '
    if 'minute' in string:
        if 'minutes' in string:
            format_string += '%M minutes '
        else:
            format_string += '%M minute '
    if 'second' in string:
        if 'seconds' in string:
            format_string += '%S seconds'
        else:
            format_string += '%S second'
    value = datetime.strptime(string, format_string)
    return value.strftime('%H:%M:%S')

string = '5 hours 20 minutes 6 seconds'
print(format_time(string))

string = '1 hour 25 seconds'
print(format_time(string))

string = '1 minute 25 seconds'
print(format_time(string))
```

**Output**

```
05:20:06
01:00:25
00:01:25
```

Comment: So datetime.strptime defaults at '00' if the seconds or hours keyword is missing?

Comment: Yes, it will be 00.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict

dataexp = [
("5 hours 20 minutes 6 seconds","05:20:06"),
("1 hour 25 seconds","01:00:25")
]

def convert(input_):
    words = input_.replace('and','').split()
    di = defaultdict(lambda:0)
    while words:
        num = int(words.pop(0))
        unit = words.pop(0)[0]
        di[unit] = num

    return f"{di['h']:02}:{di['m']:02}:{di['s']:02}"

for inp, exp in dataexp:

    got = convert(inp)
    msg = "\nfor %-100.100s \nexp :%s:\ngot :%s:\n" % (inp, exp, got)
    if exp == got:
        print("✅! %s" % msg)
    else:
        print("❌! %s" % msg)
```

which outputs:

```
✅!
for 5 hours 20 minutes 6 seconds
exp :05:20:06:
got :05:20:06:

✅!
for 1 hour 25 seconds
exp :01:00:25:
got :01:00:25:
```

Comment: Could you please explain what this code does with the ✅ values?

Comment: Oh its just test code boilerplate, nothing else.  If I dont get what I expect I put the red x.  When you have multiple complex data possible I find it nice to tell at a glance what works and what doesnt.  `convert` function is what you care about.

Comment: Oh I see, also is the `**kwds` the same as `**kwargs`?

Comment: Yup.  Not needed here.