# How to change this time data into H:M in python

Tags: python, time, numeric

Have a dataset with a duration column with time data listed as an object shown below

```
df['duration'].head(10)
    0          60 min.
    1    1 hr. 13 min.
    2    1 hr. 10 min.
    3          52 min.
    4    1 hr. 25 min.
    5          45 min.
    6          45 min.
    7          60 min.
    8          45 min.
    9          45 min.
    Name: duration, dtype: object
```

How do I change this to an appropriate numerical value, like below?

```
0    00:60
1    01:13
2    01:10
3    00:52
4    01:25
5    00:45
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert A "hours and minutes and seconds" string to HH:MM:SS format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70736772/how-to-convert-a-hours-and-minutes-and-seconds-string-to-hhmmss-format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to get a string version in `%H:%M` format and a timedelta version:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'duration':['60 min.', '1 hr. 13 min.', '1 hr. 10 min.']})
print(df)

df['parts']=df.duration.str.findall('\d+')
df['timedelta']=df.parts.apply(lambda x: pd.to_timedelta((0 if len(x) < 2 else int(x[0])) * 3600 + int(x[-1])*60, unit='s'))
df['hours and minutes']=df.parts.apply(lambda x: f"{0 if len(x) < 2 else int(x[0]):02}:{int(x[-1]):02}")
df = df.drop(columns=['duration', 'parts'])
print(df)
```

Input:

```
        duration
0        60 min.
1  1 hr. 13 min.
2  1 hr. 10 min.
```

Output:

```
        timedelta hours and minutes
0 0 days 01:00:00             00:60
1 0 days 01:13:00             01:13
2 0 days 01:10:00             01:10
```

If we do this:

```py
print(df.timedelta.dtypes)
```

... we see that the timedelta column indeed contains numerical values (of timedelta data type):

```
timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: This seems to be the best way, but I get an error when I run it... "object of type 'float' has no len()"

Comment: Is that happening with my sample input? If not, can you share the input that's giving that error?

Comment: Ah found the problem! Looks like I had 3 null variables in my column. Removed and your code is working a gem! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could apply a lambda function on your `duration` column like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

def transform(t):
    if 'hr.' in t:
        return dt.datetime.strptime(t, '%I hr. %M min.').strftime('%I:%M')
    return dt.datetime.strptime(t, '%M min.').strftime('00:%M')

df = pd.DataFrame(['45 min.', '1 hr. 13 min.'], columns=['duration'])
print(df)

df['duration'] = df['duration'].apply(lambda x: transform(x))
print(df)
```

Outputs:

```
        duration
0        45 min.
1  1 hr. 13 min.
```

and then

```
  duration
0    00:45
1    01:13
```

Note that if you want "60 min." mapped into "00:60", then you need some additional logic in the `transform` function, since the minutes format `%M` only takes values between 00-59.